# How to programmatically set the load balancer ciphers on Amazon Elastic BeansTalk?

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been reading the Amazon Elastic Beanstalk documentation, and was able to add the following lines to a configuration file in .ebextensions to set the Elastic Load Balancer to use HTTPS:

```
option_settings:
  # Elastic Load Balancer Options
  - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
    option_name: LoadBalancerHTTPPort
    value: 80
  - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
    option_name: LoadBalancerPortProtocol
    value: HTTP
  - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
    option_name: LoadBalancerHTTPSPort
    value: 443
  - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
    option_name: LoadBalancerSSLPortProtocol
    value: HTTPS
  - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
    option_name: SSLCertificateId
    value: arn:aws:iam:<my cert ARN>
```

That works perfectly. However, I was unable to find in the documentation any points on how to set the list of allowed ciphers for this load balancer without resorting to the Console or to the CLI commands. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted AWS support and confirmed that this is not yet supported. Bummer.

Comment: Is this still the case do you know?

Comment: The documentation on this shows no new options that would allow that to be automatically configured: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html. So I would assume that yes, unfortunately this is still the case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when/if this changed, but you can do this on a "classic" load balancer using `.ebextensions`:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elb:policies:tlspolicy:
    SSLProtocols: "Protocol-TLSv1.2,Server-Defined-Cipher-Order,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"
    LoadBalancerPorts: "443"
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is possible now. According to [this Elastic Load Balancer doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-security-policy-options.html), you can create your own policy:

> #### Custom Security Policy
>
> You can create a custom negotiation configuration with the ciphers and protocols that you need. Note that Some security compliance standards (such as PCI, SOX, and so on) might require a specific set of protocols and ciphers to ensure that the security standards are met. In such cases, you can create a custom security policy to meet those standards.

There are instructions at the AWS page, [Update the SSL Negotiation Configuration of Your Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-config-update.html), for using the `aws elb` command to customize a policy.

I don't want to just quote what's there, but I wanted to note that it seems possible now in case somebody else comes across the question here. In brief, though, you'd use `aws elb create-load-balancer-policy` to create a policy where you define the set of ciphers and their order, then `aws elb set-load-balancer-policies-of-listener` to enable it on your load balancers.

Comment: True, but it still seems to be unsupported in the Elastic Beanstalk Environment Configuration options, which is what my question was referencing: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html

Comment: If you add a script to do that as part of the app installation process, you would need to hard code the ELB name, right? If this was an option in the environment configuration, this would not be necessary.